# Splitting Python List Into Multiple Variables

Tags: python, list, sorting, split, leaderboard

Hi everyone I am trying to make a leaderboard for my Snake game.I have a sort working and read the sorted file back into a list from the bottom to the top(the sort I found was ascending and I needed descending).

This is the list after printing:

```
['', '47389094, purple', '', '9993, red', '', '34, Bobo', '', '19, Bob', '', '8, Jon', '', '1, Cameron']
```

I would like 10 separate variables which store the first 10 values. 
I need them to be stored as '47389094 - purple' and '9993 - red' etc so they can be displayed in an ordered table in a PyGame window.

I have tried to figure out this list splitting but I can't find any examples similar to what I want.

This is probably an inefficient way of doing it so if anyone has another idea it would be a huge help. Thanks.

Edit -

Here is the code which actually sorts the file:

```
with open('Leaderboard.csv') as sample, open('LeaderBoardSort.csv', "w") as out:
    csv1=csv.reader(sample)
    header = next(csv1, None)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(out)
    if header:
        csv_writer.writerow(header)
    csv_writer.writerows(sorted(csv1, key=lambda x:int(x[0])))
```

This suggestion here worked at first but now throws up IndexError: list index out of range. I can;t figure out what I changed to break it except adding more to the leaderboard. - NOW FIXED, I REMOVED THE SPACE BETWEEN THE COMMA AND BRACKET.

```
nl = [x.split(', ')[0] + ' - ' + x.split(', ')[1] for x in name if x]
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. The list you show has six real items and six empty strings, but you seem to want ten items? Other than getting rid of the empty strings, what do you want to be different? Is it just changing the commas for dashes? Can you show the code you're using the generate your list (since it may be easier to fix the code that puts the empty strings into the list than stripping them out after they exist)?

Comment: The list will have ten items, they have not all been added yet. I should probably have put them all in.

Comment: The extra empty spaces are added to the CSV file by the sort. I am unsure how to add a code block in a comment so this is it:                           with open('Leaderboard.csv') as sample, open('LeaderBoardSort.csv', "w") as out:
    csv1=csv.reader(sample)
    header = next(csv1, None)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(out)
    if header:
        csv_writer.writerow(header)
    csv_writer.writerows(sorted(csv1, key=lambda x:int(x[0])))

Comment: Don't put code in a comment. Instead [edit] your question to inclue the relevant code.

Comment: Ok I will do that.

Comment: I'd also note that what you're asking for (unpacking the list into ten variables) is almost certainly a very bad design. If you have a bunch of sequentially related values, a list is generally the right data structure to store them in. Unpacking is sometimes justified on small scales (maybe up to 3 or four values), but it's certainly not a good idea for ten items. Write code to loop over the list, rather than using a separate variable for each step.

Comment: I need to display them one under another in a PyGame window, the only way I know how to do it is to use variables. Bad design I know could you further explain what you mean by looping over the list?

Comment: Well, I'm assuming you're going to do something very similar with each of the scores. In that case, you can make that "something" the body of a loop rather than naming a different variable each time: `for score in list_of_scores: do_something(score)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use split, as you say, with ', ' as the split string. I then make a new list, with the hyphenated score/name as you wanted using list comprehension. (the **if x** is there to ignore the empty strings, and the **[:10]** ensures you only get the top ten scores (of course there is no sorting here, so it'd just get the first 10 elements)

```
pygame.font.init()     #initialize pygame font module
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 30)

scores = ['', '47389094, purple', '', '9993, red', '', '34, Bobo', '', '19, Bob', '', '8, Jon', '', '1, Cameron']

nl = [x.split(', ')[0] + ' - ' + x.split(', ')[1] for x in scores if x and len(x.split(', ')) == 2][:10]

for item in nl:
    score = myfont.render(item, False, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(score,(0,0))
```

This should accomplish what you are after, I think.

Comment: That worked well but it is still a list, I need to either use multiple variables to store each separate part of the list or find a way of displaying the list in the PyGame window vertically rather than horizontally. Could you explain what a list of tuples is? It could be a better solution and its always good to learn something new. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also I need it to only display the first 10 in the list.

Comment: This has for some reason stopped working, it now shows IndexError: list index out of range. I changed the CSV file a bit by adding and taking away values, should this happen?

Comment: You still use the list to show stuff in PyGame.

    #initialize the font
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)

    #loop through fonts
    for item in nl:
        label = myfont.render(item, 1, (255,255,0))`
        screen.blit(label, (100, 100))

Comment: I fixed the error I removed the space between the commas and the bracket. Don't know why it worked but it did. Now I just need to format it correctly on the screen. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I tried this and a strange black blob that look vaguely like a word appeared in the top left hand corner. Could the list contents be on top of each other? EDIT - Upon increasing font size that does indeed seem to be what  it is doing.

Comment: Figured it out now, i just had to change the coordinates each time I went through the loop. Thanks once again for your help it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Stepping back from the question, perhaps the process that loads the list could be refactored to insert/update records in a dictionary?

Since order matters you could use an OrderedDict:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: This looks like a good idea, I am not sure if I will have time to implement such a solution though I need to finish this by Monday and still have quite a bit of documentation and testing(!) to do. It is safe to say I left it a bit late.